# Using MATLAB on a cluster

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, hpc

I have a software which gets its inputs and outputs from files in text. I just need to run the software with a given input file SIM.DATA using the following command in matlab

```
[status, result]=system('eclrun -v 2014.2 SIM.DATA',-echo')
```

if I have multiple .DATA files like SIM1.DATA to SIM4.DATA, and I use a parfor lop to run the software with different input DATa files, it gives and error but when I run it with for loop it works just fine. 
I have very basic knowledge of parralel computing and cluster computing, could you please let me know what is wrong with my approach? here is a piece of code i run.

```
parfor labindex=1:4
    cmd{labindex} = ['eclrun -v 2014.2 e300  SIM',num2str(labindex),'.DATA'];
end

parfor labindex=1:4
    [status, result] = system([cmd{labindex},'.DATA'],'-echo');
end
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Is the file present on  the worker PCs?

Comment: is says: eclrun command not found , but it works when I use a for loop instead of parfor

Comment: That's a clear error message, eclrun is not found on the worker PCs, probably it is not installed.

Comment: then why is it running it with a simple for loop ?

Comment: With a for your main Matlab instance is running the command, with a parfor the worker process run the command. The workers probably run on other PCs